# export mysql data to csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-error-1045, into-outfile

I am trying to do 2 output data from mysql to a csv file.
My code is as follows:

```
public void exportData(Connection conn,String filename) {
        Statement stmt;
        String query;
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            //For comma separated file
            query = "SELECT * into OUTFILE  '/tmp/input.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM router ";
            stmt.executeQuery(query);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stmt = null;
        }
    }
};
```

I get the following error at the line where stmt.executequery is called.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'nxy'@'%' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2512)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1476)
    at DBase.exportData(automateExport.java:50)
    at automateExport.main(automateExport.java:18)
```

I am able to connect to the database properly and even execute basic queries but unable to export data to a .csv file.
Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the [FILE privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) for your user account to allow for the file to be created at the server host, via a SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE command.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there anyway I can enable it ?

Comment: You need to run GRANT FILE on "*.*" to <user>@<host> (remove quotes around star-dot-star, as Stackoverflow  is eating them up) to grant it to a user (replace the user and host tags with appropriate values for your case). Since GRANT FILE is an administrative privilege, you need to connect as root to execute it.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand why I should create file at server host??? I just want to create a file on my machine and export the data here. Could you please explain??

Comment: Is there no way to do it without using Grant File ?? As I do not have any kind of administrative access and unable to connect as root. :(

Comment: Well, in that case you'll need to write code (perhaps in Java itself) that will obtain all the rows of the table, which you can save as a CSV file (if you format the results correctly). This link might help you in assessing other options: http://support.modwest.com/content/6/135/en/how-can-i-export-data-in-csv-or-tab-delimited-format.html

Comment: Hi thanks again. I was able to get an account created for on the particular host. 
But my user account remains the same for mysql with same read access. In what way could I create the csv file now. I am not able to connect to that machine remotely either.

Comment: Well, if you are able to connect to the MySQL database via JDBC from a Java application, you should be able to perform a select on the table to extract the data and then write it to a CSV file in a location of your choice. Given your circumstances, I do not think that you will be able to write onto the database server host at all, so JDBC access appears to be the best bet.

Comment: Hi is there any way I could use mysqldump and dump all contents of the database to my machine and then export required info to a csv file
?

Comment: It's possible to have mysqldump produce a csv file containing the table dump. You need to specify the database name and the table name to the mysqldump client.

Comment: Addendum: Use the fields-terminated-by switch of mysqldump with comma as a parameter.